# Python Magickwand pdf to image converting and resize the image

Tags: imagemagick, python-2.6, magickwand

I need to create thumbnails of pdf files, and I am using Imagemagick to achieve that.

I have tried Pythonmagick and wand to convert the pdf to an image. However, when I try to resize the converted pdf, the resulting image becomes black.

Is there any option to set  `-define pdf:use-cropbox=true` using python wrappers?

Is there any other method in Python to convert a pdf to a thumbnail?

The code is as follows:

```
    import wand
    img = wand.image.Image(filename="d:\\test.pdf[0]")
    img.resize(160,160)
    img.save(filename="d:\\test.jpg")
```

Answer (score 5):

I found work around for this problem.
Convert pdf into image 1st and save the image. open newly saved image and and resize it.

```
import wand
img = wand.image.Image(filename="d:\\test.pdf[0]")
img.save(filename="d:\\temp.jpg")
img = wand.image.Image(filename="d:\\temp.jpg")
img.resize(160,160)
img.save(filename="d:\\resized_image.jpg")
```

I am still waiting for better answer.

Comment: I would suggest that the intermediate saving to "d:\\temp.jpg" used a lossless format so as not to introduce any extra compression artefacts into the final image.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem today. I found another solution in other post.
The reason why the image turns to black is that the background is transparent in PDF file. Since JPG file cannot recognize the alpha-channel (which record the transparent pixel information). JPG files will set those transparent pixel into black as default.

```
# Use the following two lines to fix this error
# img_page.background_color = Color('white')
# img_page.alpha_channel = 'remove'

with Image(filename="file.pdf",resolution= 350) as img_pdf:
    num_pages = len(img_pdf.sequence)
    for page, img in enumerate(img_pdf.sequence):
        img_page = Image(image=img)
        img_page.background_color = Color('white')
        img_page.alpha_channel = 'remove'
        img_page.resize(900,1200)
        img_page.save(filename="file"+str(page)+".jpg")
        if page == 0:
            img_page.resize(500, 500)
            img_page.save(filename="thumbnail.jpg")
```

ref: [Python Wand convert PDF to PNG disable transparent (alpha_channel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826854/python-wand-convert-pdf-to-png-disable-transparent-alpha-channel)

Comment: The calls to `resize` are likely to distort the dimensions of the images. If they're going to be displayed on a web page, better to constrain the either the height or the width (but not both) there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using temporary files - if you don't depend on JPG.

The following works for me:

```
import wand
img=wand.image.Image(filename="/home/vagrant/tmp/wand/law.pdf[0]")
img.format='png'
img.resize(220,220)
img.save(filename="/home/vagrant/tmp/wand/law_2.png")
```