# Wand can't open existing file

Tags: python, imagemagick, travis-ci, wand

I want to open a `pdf` file and get only the first page and save it as an image. 
I've used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36279291/856164) and it worked perfect. It still works in my local environment, but it fails to work in Travis recently.

So yes, this code is from my `unittest` and I'm trying to run it in Travis. 
I have a test `pdf` file and I want to open it:

```
import os
from wand.image import Image

root_path = 'some/correct/path'
filename = 'two_page_pdf.pdf'
full_path = os.path.join(root_parg, filename)
Image(file=open(full_path, mode='rb'), resolution=300) # Error!!!

-----------------------------------------------
DelegateError                             
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1b1fd9537a14> in <module>()
----> 1 Image(file=open(full_path, mode='rb'), resolution=300)

~/virtualenv/python3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wand/image.py in __init__(self, image, blob, file, filename, format, width, height, depth, background, resolution)
   2738                                                   b'buffer.' + format)
   2739                 if file is not None:
-> 2740                     self.read(file=file, resolution=resolution)
   2741                 elif blob is not None:
   2742                     self.read(blob=blob, resolution=resolution)

~/virtualenv/python3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wand/image.py in read(self, file, filename, blob, resolution)
   2820             r = library.MagickReadImage(self.wand, filename)
   2821         if not r:
-> 2822             self.raise_exception()
   2823 
   2824     def close(self):

~/virtualenv/python3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wand/resource.py in raise_exception(self, stacklevel)
    220             warnings.warn(e, stacklevel=stacklevel + 1)
    221         elif isinstance(e, Exception):
--> 222             raise e
    223 
    224     def __enter__(self):

DelegateError: Postscript delegate failed `/tmp/magick-5ypXvY6l': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/677
```

Check file:

```
os.path.isfile(full_path) == True 
len(open(full_path, mode='rb').read()) == 18386
```

Env:

- python 3.5.3
- Wand 0.4.4

What is wrong? I'm stuck. Help please

**UPD 1:**

Imagemagick pack seems to be involved in this! Last test has passed when it was version `8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.9` and it is stopped working after update to `8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.9`

**UPD 2:**

`.travis.yml` file.

```
language: python
sudo: false
cache: pip
python: "3.5"
services:
  - rabbitmq
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - imagemagick
    - python-enchant
```

Comment: Can you post your travis script? I don't believe the default vm will include PDF delegates, so you'll need to `apt-get` a few packages.

Comment: @emcconville posted!

Comment: Try adding `ghostscript` to the `addons > apt > packages`

Comment: @emcconville cool! it works now! Thank you!

Comment: @emcconville This one just got me too - ghostscript missing - any way to make the warning more explicit? :\ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error was lack of PDF delegates (`ghostscript`). I've just added this app to `addons > apt > packages` travis.yml section